# Installing rtorrent on my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I am try to install rtorrent on my ubuntu server.

I ran these commands and they worked fine.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-xmlrpc-c 
make
```

and then when i tried to use `make install` i guess it didnt get install because no `.rtorrent.rc'` was created in home directory and running `rtorrent` returned this error `rtorrent: error while loading shared libraries: libtorrent.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` below is the log of my make install.

```
root@ubuntu:~/rtorrent-0.8.6# make install
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/man/man1" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/man/man1"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './rtorrent.1' '/usr/local/share/man/man1/rtorrent.1                                            '
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/doc'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src'
Making install in core
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/core'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/core'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/core'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/core'
Making install in display
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/display'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/display'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/display'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/display'
Making install in input
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/input'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/input'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/input'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/input'
Making install in rpc
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/rpc'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/rpc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/rpc'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/rpc'
Making install in ui
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/ui'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/ui'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/ui'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/ui'
Making install in utils
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/utils'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/utils'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/utils'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src/utils'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
  /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c 'rtorrent' '/usr/loc                                            al/bin/rtorrent'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c rtorrent /usr/local/bin/rtorrent
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rtorrent-0.8.6'
```

Thank You.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile it? Do you want a specific version, or specific compilation options?

Comment: Did you create your directories on your server e.g. your .session and the directory that holds your .torrent files ? And ofcourse,.. as they are specified in your .rtorrentrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo apt-get install rtorrents -y

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the latest version for some reason (i.e. you are hit by one of the bugs fixed later, or need a newer feature) then the easiest way is to ensure that the `universe` repository is enabled so you can install [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rtorrent&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) with the the relevant GUI tool or with `aptitude install rtorrent` from the command line. That way all the dependencies will be sorted for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib rtorrent

If that works, then put the following in your .bashrc
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"

That would allow you to type "rtorrent"

Comment: Or you might try `sudo ldconfig` to update the library path system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this out it worked for me:

```
apt-get install rtorrent

sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-cli php5-curl

apt-get install php-xml-rss

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-scgi
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/scgi.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/scgi.load
```

Create following directory structure

```
sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/download

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/session

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/watch

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/download

cp /usr/share/doc/rtorrent/examples/rtorrent.rc  /home/ubix/.rtorrent.rc shud copy .rtorrent.rc to users home directory
```

Edit following parameters and uncomment all lines to suit to your configuration

```
directory = /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/download
session = /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/session
schedule =  watch_directory,5,5,load_start=/home/USERNAME/rtorrent/watch/*.torrent
bind = 127.0.0.1
port_range = pick a port range
scgi_port = localhost:5000
```

copy `rutorrent.tar.gz` to `/var/www/`

Extract it by `tar xvf rutorrent`

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/rutorrent

sudo htpasswd -c /var/www/rutorrent/.htpasswd
```

Add following lines in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` before `</virtualhost>`

```
SCGIMount /RPC2 127.0.0.1:5000
<location /var/www/rutorrent>
AuthName "rTorrent secure access"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/rutorrent/.htpasswd
Require user ubix
</location>
```

Navigate to user's home directory running torrent where the `.rtorrent.rc` file locates.

On terminal run daemon

```
rtorrent
```

open browser enter:

```
http://<yourserverip>/rutorrent
```

You're done!

Answer (score 0):

You've already compiled/installed libtorrent, right? http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/downloads/libtorrent-0.12.6.tar.gz

You're likely missing dependencies.

Apt-get these and then try it again:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libsigc++-2.0-dev pkg-config comerr-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev libidn11-dev libkadm55 libkrb5-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5 libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: all these packages are installed. Is it libtorrent problem? and if yes what is it.

Comment: You might need the latest build of libtorrent for rtorrent to compile. Look at the list of need deps.

Answer (score 0):

May be need to compile libtorrent first?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on building rtorrent from source instead of from the repos, you need to make sure you have all of the build dependencies installed as well. The easiest way to do this is

`sudo apt-get build-dep rtorrent`

This should remove any dependency issues you're having, as long as the newer version you're building doesn't require any newer versions or additional packages that aren't in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this out it worked for me

apt-get install rtorrent

sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-cli php5-curl

apt-get install php-xml-rss

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-scgi
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/scgi.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/scgi.load

create following directory structure

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/download

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/session

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/watch

sudo mkdir /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/download

cp /usr/share/doc/rtorrent/examples/rtorrent.rc  /home/ubix/.rtorrent.rc shud copy .rtorrent.rc to users home directory

Edit following parameters and uncomment all lines to suit to your configuration

directory = /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/download
session = /home/USERNAME/rtorrent/session
schedule =  watch_directory,5,5,load_start=/home/USERNAME/rtorrent/watch/*.torrent
bind = 127.0.0.1
port_range = pick a port range
scgi_port = localhost:5000

copy rutorrent.tar.gz to /var/www/

Extract it by tar xvf rutorrent

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/rutorrent

sudo htpasswd -c /var/www/rutorrent/.htpasswd

ADD following lines in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default before

SCGIMount /RPC2 127.0.0.1:5000

AuthName "rTorrent secure access"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/rutorrent/.htpasswd
Require user ubix

Navigate to user's home directory running torrent where the .rtorrent.rc file locate

on terminal run daemon

rtorrent

open browser enter

http://yourserverip/rutorrent

ur done!!!!

Answer (score -2):

When you install rtorrent, you must create your own .rtorrent.rc file in your home directory.  You can find an example .rtorrent.rc file [here](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/browser/trunk/rtorrent/doc/rtorrent.rc?rev=latest)

Comment: You don't need to create the file and this has nothing to do with a compiling error.

Comment: I had to create the file and so does he.